# Efficiency of C Code

Tags: c, hex

I’ve created a small program used to generate random hexadecimal color codes. It compiles and runs without errors, but as I’m new to this, I’m questioning the efficiency of the code and looking for explanations for possible optimization.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int i, r;
    time_t t;
    char hexadecimal[7];

    char* hex[16];
    hex[0] = "0";
    hex[1] = "1";
    hex[2] = "2";
    hex[3] = "3";
    hex[4] = "4";
    hex[5] = "5";
    hex[6] = "6";
    hex[7] = "7";
    hex[8] = "8";
    hex[9] = "9";
    hex[10] = "A";
    hex[11] = "B";
    hex[12] = "C";
    hex[13] = "D";
    hex[14] = "E";
    hex[15] = "F";  

    strcpy(hexadecimal, "#");

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        r = rand() % 16;
        strcat(hexadecimal, hex[r]);
    }   
    printf("%s\n", hexadecimal);

    return 0;
}
```

Again, the program compiles and runs without errors, but I’m skeptical. Any tips or corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, it isn't the most efficient pickle in the jar. Stack Overflow isn't for these sorts of questions. If you have working code and looking for review or optimization tips, try on Code Review.

Comment: Pretty much the exact answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: if you use the printf format specifier for hex values, you won't need to make a mapping at all.  `printf("%2x", hex);`

Comment: `printf("#%06x", rand() % (256 * 256 * 256));` -- is way simpler. I don't know if it is faster.

Comment: @DeiDei Code is not quite working with its UB of overflowing `hexadecimal[7];`  Needs to be at least 1 more.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, good thought or if you need to capture the code in a variable, maybe `char hex[8]; snprintf (hex, 8, "#%06x, rand() % 0x1000000);` (or as augmented with @chux answer below)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed, chux's answer is really thorough!

Comment: Don't work with strings but with chars : `char* hex[16]; ... ` -> `char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF"; `. And modify the rest accordingly.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: if `RAND_MAX` is smaller than 2^24 (and it's often 2^15), this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code is pretty inefficient.  This is a good opportunity to learn about the way characters and strings work together in C.  Knowing that, we can write a much tighter version.  It will run that much more quickly, and as a bonus it may also be somewhat easier to write, and to read.

(Side note: your `hexadecimal` array was one too small.  We need space for the `'#'`, plus 6 hexadecimal digits, plus the terminating `'\0'`.  So it needs to be `char hexadecimal[8]`.)

We're going to build up the `hexadecimal` string using characters, not strings.  So instead of `hex` being an array of strings, let's have it be an array of characters:

```
char hex[16];
hex[0] = '0';
hex[1] = '1';
/* ... */
```

But wait, an array of characters is a string.  So instead we can write:

```
char hex[16] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

or just:

```
char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
```

(There's a slight difference between the two, but for this program it won't matter one way or the other.)

And now, instead of using `strcat` to concatenate the `hex[r]` strings onto the string we're building, we're going to place the `hex[r]` characters directly into the string we're building:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    r = rand() % 16;
    hexadecimal[i+1] = hex[r];
}
```

You'll notice that I assigned to `hexadecimal[i+1]`, not `hexadecimal[i]`.  We have to "shift everything over to the right" by one, because the string already contains the leading `'#'`.  Another way to do this (though unusual in C) would be to use a 1-based loop:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    r = rand() % 16;
    hexadecimal[i] = hex[r];
}
```

Also, since we're building up the string a character at a time, explicitly, we might as well do our leading `'#'` character that way, too, by going back and changing

```
strcpy(hexadecimal, "#");
```

to

```
hexadecimal[0] = '#';
```

There's one more thing we have to do.  Since we've been building up the string a character at a time, by hand, we have to take care of the null termination by hand, too:

```
hexadecimal[7] = '\0';
```

But in the end this will do the same thing: generate a well-formed string `hexadecimal` containing six random hex digits:

```
printf("%s\n", hexadecimal);
```

---

And, before I go, a footnote about efficiency.  I said "Yes, your code is pretty inefficient", and I claimed that my rewrite will run "that much more quickly".  And while that's true, it's all relative.  Even the "inefficient" version will run much more quickly than you can measure, and the difference between the two versions will be almost imperceptible.

Me, I would write the character-at-a-time version anyway, because I'm an old-school C kind of guy, and I think that way.  But if there were some reason to prefer the `strcat` version -- if it was easier or quicker to write, or easier to read, or easier to get right in the first place -- we might prefer it anyway, and just not worry about its "inefficiency".

Just for fun, I compiled and ran both versions on my laptop.  The "inefficient" version took 0.002s of user time, as measured by the Unix 'time' command.  The "more efficient" version took... 0.002s.  So whatever the difference is, it's smaller than a millisecond, and it's swamped by overhead issues, like the time taken for the program to start up at all.

So I added another loop to both programs so that they generated 1,000,000 random hex strings.  Now there was a difference: The inefficient version took 0.404s, and the efficient version took 0.263s.  (Think about it: One million random strings, in less than half a second.  Computers are very, very fast.)  Dividing it out, the inefficient version took 0.404 ÷ 1000000 = .000000404s per iteration, or 404 *nanoseconds*.  The efficient version, on the other hand, took just 263 nanoseconds.  So, yes, the efficient version is more efficient -- but unless you need a *lot* of these random hex values, you will never notice the difference.

---

One more footnote.  There's a serious potential problem with the line

```
r = rand() % 16;
```

Most annoyingly, there are implementations of `rand()` out there that are *not* very random in the low-order bits.  So if you grab just the low-order bits, as you do here, you can end up with a sequence that's totally non-random, that goes through the same sequence of 16 values every time.

The easiest way to fix this (assuming it's available to you) is to switch to the better `random()` function:

```
r = random() % 16;
```

If you do this, you need to use its companion `srandom` function:

```
srandom((unsigned) time(&t));
```

(Side question: when the problem with `rand()` was discovered, why didn't someone just fix it, instead of leaving it broken and inventing a newer but slightly less standard function that works better, and hoping everyone remembers to use it instead?  I honestly don't know.)

If `random()` is not available to you, you can dodge `rand`'s problem by using its higher-order bits, like this:

```
r = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 16 + 1);
```

See also the [C FAQ list](http://c-faq.com/), questions [13.16](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html) and [13.18](http://c-faq.com/lib/notveryrand.html).

Answer (score 4):

`char hexadecimal[7];` is too small to hold a *string* like `"#123456"` which needs 8 `char`.

---

Repeated calls to `strcat(hexadecimal, hex[r]);` is inefficient.  Each `strcat()` can be expected to "cost" the length of the existing string.  To loop `n` times and `strcat()` a long string of `n` character takes `O(n*n)` time.  More efficient to keep track of the end of the string and append there.

Yet let us do this without a *string*.

---

`rand()` will generates an `int` value `[0.. RAND_MAX]`.   `RAND_MAX` may be as small as `0x7FFF` or as great as `INT_MAX`.  [Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx)

Code is looking to generate 6 * 4 bits of random data.  So call `rand()` 1 or 2 times rather than 6.

```
// for rand(), uint32_t, printf(), PRIX32
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
  // srand() omitted for simplicity,  let OP add back in

  uint32_t r = rand();
  if (RAND_MAX < 0xFFFFFF) {
    r += r*RAND_MAX;  // like r = r*(RAND_MAX + 1) yet avoids RAND_MAX + 1 overflow
    r += rand();
  }

  // We only want 24-bits
  r &= 0xFFFFFF;
  // If RAND_MAX is a Mersenne Number  M=2^n-1, 
  // then `r` value is no more biased than `rand()`

  printf("#%06" PRIX32 "\n", r);
}
```

Note: The time to do I/O is often 100s of time more than the rest of this code.